# Long Boolean Where in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

CLOSED.  I had a mistake somewhere else unrelated to the boolean.

What am I doing wrong here in this SQL where:

```
WHERE (country = 'HK') OR (country = 'TW') OR (country = 'AX')
```

It’s missing the result for AX in the output.

What am I doing wrong with this Boolean expression?

Note1.  ' at end of AX was my typo here. I corrected above.

Full code here

```
$myresult = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['DBlink'],
    "SELECT $getcolumn 
     FROM levermann 
     WHERE 
        ( $sqlwhere2 ) AND 
        levermann.`WEEK` = 
            (SELECT `WEEK`, COUNT(*) AS cc 
            FROM levermann 
            WHERE ( $sqlwhere2 ) 
            GROUP BY `WEEK` 
            HAVING cc > 4 
            ORDER BY `WEEK` DESC 
            LIMIT 1 )
        AND $lswitch AND $marketcap 
    ORDER BY LScore2 DESC, MarketCAPUSD DESC, Stock_Short ASC 
    LIMIT 10;");

if  ($region == 'ASIA') {
    $sqlwhere2 = "
        ( country = 'HK' ) OR 
        ( country = 'TW' ) OR 
        ( country = 'AX' ) OR 
        ( country = 'KS' ) OR 
        ( country = 'SS' )";
    $region='Asia';
}

if  ($region == 'Global') {
    $sqlwhere2 = " country  like '%'"; 
    $region='Global';
}

if  ($region == 'US') {
    $sqlwhere2 = " country  = 'US'"; 
    $region='US';
}
```

Comment: Check the quote next to `AX`, it looks weird

Comment: The brackets are unnecessary, but you need to show use the whole query along with a sample of the data.

Comment: Are you sure there's data for the given criteria? Have you tested your query thoroughly?

Comment: I am sorry but I found the error somewhere else unrelated. I am not going to delete this question because SO says better to keep it.  Thanks everyone for helping out so fast!

Answer (score 3):

There is a special character at the end enclosing `'AX‘`

Also why not just use `in()` instead?

```
WHERE country in ('HK','TW','AX')
```

Comment: Yes was my typo.  I meant to put '. It’s correct in the code.

Comment: I will try the in() next

Answer (score 0):

Entire statement should be in brackets

Edit: also wrong quote at the end

```
WHERE (country = 'HK' OR country = 'TW' OR country = 'AX')
```

Comment: The brackets are unnecessary if those are the only logical statements in the `WHERE` clause. I find that brackets make things more readable, but only if they're used in the right way. The key thing was the apostrophe on the end.

Comment: It’s not to do with the brackets since I have added the extra () brackets around the whole Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in the condition
 `(country = 'AX‘)`
you are not using the ending '' correctly.please correct and check it